# create own class extended from UITableVIewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

i have own class which is extends from UITableViewController.
After this line 
MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
i have
obj.view.frame.orign.y = 20

after i push this custom view via navigation controller - i check y coordinate in viewDidAppear and it became 0.
so strange

Why ? Is it because my custom table view below status bar which height is 20 ?
 or something else.
If it because status bar, why i can create UIButton in (0,0) and it below status bar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior that you see is normal:
- You first create your view controller, it is not attached to a view hierarchy, by default it takes the coordinate as if it was the root controller, y=20 because of the status bar
- Then you push the view controller, it is resized to fit in the navigation controller, the frame coordinates are the coordinates in relation to the parent frame , i.e. y=0 is the top of the navigation controller, which is equivalent to y=20 in the main window. pushViewController resizes the frame, see documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> The view is automatically resized to fit between the navigation bar
>   and toolbar (if present) before it is displayed.

Comment: i only create object like MyClass *obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
and then NSLog y-coordinate of frame and got 20

Comment: so? I don't understand the question. In that order: 1)create your object as you've been doing 2)push it to the navigation stack  3)set your frame coordinates 4)check with your NSLog statement.  You seem to be setting your frame before pushing it on the stack, the pushViewController statement is resizing your view controller

Comment: one more time
1) create object
2) nslog y - have 20
3) push them
4) nslog y - have 0
question - why on step 2 y = 20?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide the complete explanation, let me know if this makes sense. the y=20 you first get is in relation to the main window (with status bar). After you push your controller, the frame coordinates are the coordinates WITHIN the navigation controller's frame, i.e. y=0 in that frame corresponds to y=20 in the main window